# How can I run pydoc when it doesn't appear to be on the PATH?

Tags: macos, python-3.5, pydoc

I am using MACOSX 10.12.3 and Python 3.52

I am running into issues when running pydoc in a bash script in python IDLE.
For example:

```py
    myFile = ‘/home/user/afile.py’
    import subprocess
    subprocess.run([‘pydoc’, ‘-w’, myFile])
```

Inevitably does not create the html file as would be expected.
On the other hand, when I run pydoc in the terminal

```
pydoc3 -w /home/user/afile.py
```

it always creates the wanted html file.  But `pydoc -w /home/user/afile.py` generates an error

This is due to the fact that:

1. the python `/home/user/afile.py` contains a few print statements in python3 style.  That is:  `print('blabla')` instead of:  `print 'blabla'` as would be the case on python2.
2. the bash script in IDLE does not load the correct pydoc.  I should also mention that running `subprocess.run([‘pydoc3’, ‘-w’, myFile])` generates an error, for example:

> subprocess.run(['pydoc3', '-w', myFile])   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py",
> line 693, in run
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py",
> line 947, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py",
> line 1551, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pydoc3'

Any one has a way to circumvent this please?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:
Regarding running the python 3 version of pydoc against python 2 code- That will not work. Pydoc will execute (import) the target module. You would need to use python 2 version of pydoc by modifying your path or using your favorite virtual environment tool.

Question 2:
If you can get a reference to your desired installation of python (by setting the path or activating a virtual environment), then you can handle missing or broken entry points with this syntax:

`python -m pydoc -w myfile`

You will also need to make sure `myfile` is in the current directory or on the PYTHONPATH or otherwise importable